# Some basic questions regarding jQuery code

Tags: jquery, function, class, element

I'm new learning JQuery and is trying to figure out some basic stuff. Would appreciate some help about three questions:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ADbanner = '<img src="http://image.banana.com/is/image/banana/checkout?$checkout%20shopping%20bag%20image$" class="ADscratch_img" />';  

    $(".right-space").after(ADbanner);
});
```

1. When will this function execute?
2. What element is this function selecting?
3. How is this function manipulating this element?

I know for the first question the function will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded. Right now `class="ADscratch_img"` does not make much sense to me. I know the function is maybe moving the image, but not sure what  `$(".right-space").after(ADbanner);` means.

Answer (score 0):

**When will this function execute?**

This executes once the document is ready after receiving all the resources. That is, when an event [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) is triggered.

**What element is this function selecting?**

This function selects **all** the elements with the class `right-space`.

**How is this function manipulating this element?**

The function finds the element with the class `right-space` and next to the element, it adds the HTML:

```
<img src="http://image.banana.com/is/image/banana/checkout?$checkout%20shopping%20bag%20image$" class="ADscratch_img" />
```

This means, after that element, it will be adding an image.

Answer (score 0):

1. This will run when the document's DOM is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
2. The element(s) being selected are all those with a class of `right-space`
3. [After](http://api.jquery.com/after/) all elements with class `right-space` an image is being appended.

Answer (score 0):

- The line `$(document).ready(function(){})` tells the function to execute when the document (the webpage) is finished loading.
- The inner JQuery says to select all elements that have the class, "`.right-space`" and then
- inserts an image by writing HTML (using img tags) after the selected element (the one with the `.right-space` class attribute).

Answer (score 0):

> When will this function execute?

This function will execute on DOM ready. That is, this function will execute when the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event is fired.

> What element is this function selecting?

This function is selecting ***all*** of the elements with a class of `right-space`.

> How is this function manipulating this element?

This function is placing the following HTML snippet:

```
<img src="http://image.banana.com/is/image/banana/checkout?$checkout%20shopping%20bag%20image$" class="ADscratch_img" />
```

after each of the matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

that function will be executed on document ready (you can put an alert("something") to see when it is executed.

about what the function is selecting,.. well the only selector you have there is the right-space class

and what is manipulating? is manipulating the element that you selected,

you are adding that img tag to the end of the .right-space element.

Answer (score 0):

> When will this function execute?

Since you're putting your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** , it will be executed on page load

> What element is this function selecting?

`$(".right-space")` will match any element in your page with class `right-space`

> How is this function manipulating this element?

`$(".right-space").after(ADbanner);` will insert `ADbanner` which is an image after any element with class `right-space`. Refer to **[.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**

Also take a tour to the offical **[learning center](https://learn.jquery.com/)** of jQuery

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/783g3/)**